# Iterate columns in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am working on `RDD`, I am stuck as per how to iterate through columns in a single tuple through looping techniques. For example, anything similar to following:

```
def doSomething(rdd: RDD[(Int, Int, Int)], col: Int) = {
     for(i <- 0 until col) {
         val count = rdd.map(f => f._i).count //how to use 'i' to iterate?
     }
}
```

Although it is a useless example but I want to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a tuple by index using productElement

```
val t = (1, 2, 3)
t.productElement(0) == t._1
```

Here is its implementation from scala.Product3:

```
override def productElement(n: Int) = n match {
   case 0 => _1
   case 1 => _2
   case 2 => _3
   case _ => throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(n.toString())
}
```

So you should update your code as follows:

```
def doSomething(rdd: RDD[(Int, Int, Int)], col: Int) = {
    for(i <- 0 until col) {
        val count = rdd.map(f => f.productElement(i)).count //this is how you use 'i' 
    }
}
```